# ¿Cómo ejecutar correctamente servicio de mongodb (mongod.exe)?

Tags: mongodb

Estoy teniendo un problema para poder ejecutar MongoDB en mi pc. Tengo Windows 7 de 32 bits. Ya le instalé un hotfix que decía la página que necesitaba instalar y sigue sin dejarme iniciar el servicio. Adjunto un screenshot de la consola de windows con lo que me sale. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa este comando espero que te fucione
mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como iniciar el proceso, es como lo estas realizando, no es necesario escribir mongod.exe, simplemente desde la linea de comandos, dentro del folder `/bin` :

> mongod.exe

Me llamo la atención el mensaje de error, recuerda que debes crear primeramente el folder donde se crearan los [datos](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/glossary/#term-dbpath)

> md data\db

cuando este creado el directorio ejecuta nuevamente el proceso.

Yo he usado únicamente las versiones de Mongo 2.* y 3.* de 64 bits, y el único problema que he tenido es con los permisos de `/data/db/`, tu mensaje
indica que en las versiones de 32 bits no tiene la propiedad journaling habilitada por default.

```
storage.journal.enabled
Tipo: boolean    
Default: true es sistemas de 64-bit, false en sistemas de 32-bit
```

Revisa el documento de **[configuración](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file)**

Puedes crear un archivo mongod.cfg

```
C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg
```

el cual contendrá:

```
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
```

para usarlo cuando inicies el proceso :

> mongod.exe --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg"

o puedes tratar también

> mongod.exe --journal

---

**Al final tuve el mismo problema y en este caso no era habilitar la propiedad `journaling`, es especificar diferente motor de almacenamiento:**

```
> mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

Comment: La carpeta data\db ya la había creado anteriormente, incluso en la consola no aparece ningún error respecto a esto.

Comment: trata con journal = true dentro de tu mongo.config

Comment: ¿Cómo accedo al mongo.config? No veo ese archivo en la carpeta de mongodb

Comment: Ya pude resolver el problema. Al parecer la versión 3.2.4 tiene problemas en Windows 7 de 32 bits. Tuve que instalar la 3.0 y ya sirvió

Comment: veo que usas precisamente mongodb 3.2, ve mi respuesta, veo que ahora es storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true ...... trata con mongod.exe --journal

Comment: mm ok en esa versión me parece que la propiedad journaling esta habilitada https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/journaling/ , no hubieras desisntalado todo =( hubieras tratado de realizar la configuración!