# ¿Error el iniciar mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

[image: Esto es el error que me muestra.]

Ya ejecuté los comandos mongod y después mongo que son los que aparecen en la documentación de mongodb, pero me salen esos errores.
Tambié ya tengo creado el siguiente directorio **C:\data\db**

Comment: Friky ve mi respuesta y comenta que obtienes.

Comment: @Elenasys Tu respuesta a funcionado muy bien.

Comment: Exceente Friky, me da mucho gusto, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando una versión de 32 bits, el problema es :

> 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default

y se resuelve en base a lo que especifica el mensaje que obtienes al iniciar el daemon:

```
> mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

Revisa esta respuesta la cual tuvo un problema similar, te recomiendo primero trates habilitando la propiedad `journaling`:

[¿Cómo ejecutar correctamente servicio de mongodb (mongod.exe)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7402/c%C3%B3mo-ejecutar-correctamente-servicio-de-mongodb-mongod-exe/7405#7405)

Answer (score 0):

Elimina la carpeta

```
C:\data\db,
```

despues vuelve a crearla, si tu mongodb no esta en path. Abre tu consola y teclea

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin,
```

despues

```
mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

para saber si el problema esta resuelto utiliza

```
mongodb
```

Para poder visualizar tus collections descarga el Robomongo [Descargar](https://robomongo.org/)

[image: Visualizar]

Configuralo como en la Imagen y podras visualizar tus colecciones

[image: Ejemplo]